# Anyone get the MacPorts' Mercurial package to work with MercurialEclipse plugin?

Tags: macos, mercurial, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to get the Mercurial Eclipse plugin to use my MacPorts version of Mercurial (since I need to access a repo that's using the new dotencode format), but I can't get the Mercurial preference page under "Team" to save the changes. It will recognize "/opt/local/bin" as a valid directory for the "hg" executable, but when exiting the workspace the changes don't appear to be saved properly, since the next time I launch Eclipse, the old "/usr/local/bin" is back there again.

Has anyone else had problems with this? "/opt/local/bin/hg" is a symlink to "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/hg" on my system, but that file also contains a shebang ("#!") with the same path (duh!). Is that known to cause any problems on anyone else's machine?

Edit: Symlinking `/usr/local/bin/hg` to `/opt/local/bin/hg` works, but this doesn't fix the cause of the problem.
There are no errors being logged in the Eclipse Error Log view, other than "abort: requirement 'dotencode' not supported!" on startup. I.e. no errors on validating the settings or when saving the workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have another version of `hg` in `/usr/local/bin`?  If not or if you no longer need it, you might be able to work around the issue by making a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/hg /usr/local/bin/hg
sudo chmod -h g+rx,o+rx /usr/local/bin/hg
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip (it works!). But it doesn't solve the cause of the problem - Eclipse won't save the preferences across restarts.

Comment: To get at the root cause, the most likely cause would be some sort of file or directory permissions problem.  I don't know enough about Eclipse to give concrete suggestions but, if you are comfortable with playing with commands like `find` and `chmod`, you could try tracking down where Eclipse saves preferences.  A longer shot: try looking in the various system logs; often OS X apps will end up leaving messages there.  The easy way to do that is to use `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`.  Good luck!